# Getting GCC's output from command line when running it through C#

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, c#-3.0

I'm currently compiling a C program through my C# app. **If gcc outputs anything it means that there was an error. I want to retrieve this error and display it to the user.**

Currently, I'm doing this...

```
        var proc = new Process
        {
            StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo
            {
                FileName = _cCompilerPath,
                Arguments = " ./file.c",
                UseShellExecute = false,
                RedirectStandardOutput = true,
                CreateNoWindow = true                    
            }
        };

        proc.Start();
        string message = string.Empty;
        while (!proc.StandardOutput.EndOfStream)
        {
            string line = proc.StandardOutput.ReadLine();
            message = string.Concat(message, line);      
        }
        MessageBox.Show("OUTPUT :" + message);
```

But even when there is an error in the program, nothing gets redirected to the Standard Output, and the EndOfStream always returns true.

Comment: Does `gcc` write to `StandardError` by chance?

Comment: Oh my god, it probably does. Brain choke! I'll check and get back!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would bet that it's writing to `StandardError` instead.

```
    RedirectStandardError = true,

    ....

    while (!proc.StandardError.EndOfStream)
    {
        string line = proc.StandardError.ReadLine();
        message = string.Concat(message, line);      
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `Console.WriteLine("message");` if you are working with the console. The `MessageBox` is for WinForms applications.

```
Console.WriteLine("OUTPUT: {0}", message);
```

`Console.WriteLine` writes to the standard output.

Comment: No, no...I do want it in a Message Box. I'll be displaying it in a custom message box though.